# Uploading a file via Post Request

Tags: java, post, jersey, http-post

I am attempting to upload images to SmugMug via HTTP Post as per their [documentation](http://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/Uploading). I have all the headers correct, but the part that is confusing me is setting the binary data in the body as stated:

> This method requires a POST request with the binary data in the body
>   and all other metadata in the headers.

I have tried:

- ```
  SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath()));
  ```
- ```
  SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, new String(Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath())));
  ```
- ```
  SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, new String(Base64.encode(Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath()))));
  ```
- ```
  SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, Base64.encode(Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath())));
  ```

My best guess was the first one would work, but all of these return:

```
{"stat":"fail","method":"smugmug.images.upload","code":5,"message":"system error"}
```

Here is the full method that does the uploading, in case I missed something:

```
public boolean upload(File image, int albumId, String caption, String keywords, 
        Boolean hidden, Integer imageId, Integer altitude, Float latitude, 
        Float longitude, boolean pretty) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SmugMugException {
    logger.debug("upload() called");
    byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath());

    WebResource resource = SmugMugAPI.CLIENT.resource("http://upload.smugmug.com/");

    LoggingFilter logFilter = new LoggingFilter();
    resource.addFilter(logFilter);

    OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret(smugmug.getConsumerSecret());
    OAuthParameters oauthParams = new OAuthParameters().consumerKey(smugmug.getCosumerKey()).
            signatureMethod("HMAC-SHA1").version("1.0");
    // Create the OAuth client filter
    OAuthClientFilter filter = new OAuthClientFilter(SmugMugAPI.CLIENT.getProviders(), oauthParams, secrets);
    // Add the filter to the resource
    if (smugmug.getToken() != null){
        secrets.setTokenSecret(smugmug.getToken().getSecret());
        oauthParams.token(smugmug.getToken().getId());
    }
    resource.addFilter(filter);

    WebResource.Builder builder = resource.getRequestBuilder();
    //User agent
    builder = builder.header("User-Agent", smugmug.getAppName());
    //API Version header
    builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Version", "1.3.0");
    //Response Type header
    builder = builder.header("X-Smug-ResponseType", "JSON");
    //Content-Length header
    builder = builder.header("Content-Length", Long.toString(image.length()));
    //Content-MD5 header
    builder = builder.header("Content-MD5", DigestUtils.md5Hex(imageBytes));
    //X-Smug-FileName header
    builder = builder.header("X-Smug-FileName", image.getName());
    //X-Smug-AlbumID header
    builder = builder.header("X-Smug-AlbumID", Integer.toString(albumId));
    //X-Smug-Caption header
    if(caption != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Caption", caption);
    }
    //X-Smug-Caption header
    if(keywords != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Keywords", keywords);
    }
    //X-Smug-Hidden header
    if(hidden != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Hidden", hidden.toString());
    }
    //X-Smug-ImageID header
    if(imageId != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-ImageID", imageId.toString());
    }
    //X-Smug-Altitude header
    if(altitude != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Altitude", altitude.toString());
    }
    //X-Smug-Latitude header
    if(latitude != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Latitude", latitude.toString());
    }
    //X-Smug-Latitude header
    if(longitude != null){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Longitude", longitude.toString());
    }
    //X-Smug-Pretty header
    if(pretty){
        builder = builder.header("X-Smug-Pretty", Boolean.toString(pretty));
    }

    SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, new String(imageBytes));
    if (!"ok".equals(response.getStat())) {
        throw new SmugMugException(response);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

---

Tried just to see the response:

```
SMResponse response = builder.entity(image).post(SMResponse.class);
```

It actually sent back a blank response (no json) which is odd in itself, as I would have expected some message back. Here is the output:

```
Nov 21, 2012 11:55:48 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Edge-Control: no-store
1 < X-SmugMug-Hiring: How to love what you do: http://www.smugmug.com/jobs/
1 < Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2012 05:55:48 GMT
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < X-SmugMug-Values: 4/4 - It's the product, stupid
1 < Expires: Thu, 22 Nov 2012 05:55:49 GMT
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
1 < X-Powered-By: SmugMug/0.9
1 < Server: Apache
1 < Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, max-age=1, must-revalidate
1 <
```

Comment: Can you try SMResponse response = builder.entity(image).post(SMResponse.class);

Comment: @Reddy The problem with that is where do I set the data for the image itself in that case.

Comment: It's essentially an HTTP request, so try to capture the traffic with debug tools like Fiddler/BurpSuite, I find this approach especially useful when trying to locate the problem.

Comment: What data you need to set for the image apart from the headers you have already set?

Comment: @Reddy The "binary data" as they call it in the docs of the image I am uploading to SmugMug. I assume it is the byte[] of the file itself.

Comment: @infgeoax Fiddler seems pretty cool, but since I am on OS X a little harder to set up. If I can't figure this out tonight, I will give that a shot tomorrow after waking from the turkey induced comma.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's needed, but it seems you're not sending a Content-Type header for your posted entity? (I'd also just pass raw bytes to Jersey and let its message body writers & filters handle how to put it onto the message best...)

Comment: @jschoen, though it is blank response response code is 200 so I think it is working fine. Can you check if your call actually uploaded that image?

Comment: @Reddy I just double checked by running it again, and it does not upload the image. Which seems correct as I never gave it the data in the image file.

Comment: @jschoen, Is there any error showing up in your control panel?
see http://www.dgrin.com/showpost.php?p=1824821&postcount=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what happened, but I was able to get it working after finding the Upload Log in the SmugMug Account Settings (To get there go to Tools -> Account Settings -> Stats -> Uploads -> Details). Note that in the upload log there is a toggle to show only errors or all uploads.

Now on to the actual answer to how to set the actual "body" of the Post Request. The actual format should have been the first one I posted:

```
SMResponse response = builder.post(SMResponse.class, Files.readAllBytes(image.toPath()));
```

So either I messed up, and thought it was not working when it was, there was a problem on smugmug's end at the time, or there was something else in my code that was wrong, that got fixed in the process of me trying to fix this non-issue.